# How can I reset the Math Symbol Autocorrect in word?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-word

How can you

1. Reset the math autocorrect pairing between shortcuts of e.g. the form \scriptF and the mathematic symbol to default settings?
2. How can you add a shortcut to a mathematic symbol that already exists in Word, but does not yet have an associated "\shortcut" shortcut?

Motivation for the question:
I by mistake deleted the \scriptF shortcut from the list and want to reinstate it, but haven't found a way that does not involve manually editing files in the Word directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy enough to add back a missing symbol such as `\scriptF`:

- Go into *File > Options*
- In section "Proofing", under "AutoCorrect options", click the button
  *AutoCorrect Options...*
- In tab "Math AutoCorrect", type under "Replace:" `\scriptF`
  and next to it the value `ℱ`
- If `\scriptF` doesn't exist, the *Add* button will be enabled
- Click *Add*
- Click OK.

If you wish to reset all of Office :

- Run *Control Panel > Programs and Features*
- Right-click your "Microsoft 365" version and select "Change"
- Authorize elevation
- In the dialog select "Online Repair" and click "Repair".

Comment: Thank you very much for answering the question! So I simply have to find the ℱ in its \scriptF form somewhere (e.g. your reply) to copy-paste it, but there is no list in Word itself with all "possible " or "pre-defined" symbols?

Comment: The list in "Math AutoCorrect" contains all the defined symbols. I understood that you have deleted `\scriptF` and outlined here a method for bringing it back.